# Adding commas to geom_text labels in ggplot

Tags: r, parsing, ggplot2, scale

I have a dataset where I am interested in looking at a score on a test and the percentage of people experiencing an event:

```
dat <- data.frame(score = 1:7,
              n.event = c(263,5177,3599,21399,16228,10345,1452),
              n.total = c(877,15725,13453,51226,32147,26393,7875),
              percentage = c(30,33,27,42,50,39,18))
```

I can plot it with the percentages and fractions like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=score, y=percentage)) +
 geom_line() +
 geom_text(aes(label = paste0(dat$percentage,"*\'%\'~","frac(",dat$n.event, 
                              ",", dat$n.total, ")")),parse = TRUE)
```

[image: Data plot from preceding code]

However, I can't seem to figure out how to add commas in the fractions. This doesn't work like I thought it would:

```
library(scales)
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=score, y=percentage)) +
 geom_line() +
 geom_text(aes(label = paste0(dat$percentage,"*\'%\'~","frac(",comma(dat$n.event), 
                              ",", comma(dat$n.total), ")")),parse = TRUE)
```

[image: Data plot from preceding code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commas in the numbers are confusing `frac`.

You can see the problem with the simpler

```
geom_text(aes(label = "frac(1,000, 2,000)"), parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

We need to use characters within `frac` to get the desired output.  If using double quotes around the statement, you can use single quotes around the values.

```
geom_text(aes(label = "frac('1,000', '2,000')"), parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

So you could wrap your `comma` statements within single quotes for the `frac` section of your labels.

```
geom_text(aes(label = paste0("frac('", comma(dat$n.event), "','", 
                            comma(dat$n.total), "')")), parse = TRUE)
```

The whole statement would be

```
geom_text(aes(label = paste0(dat$percentage, "*\'%\'~", "frac('", comma(dat$n.event), 
                            "','", comma(dat$n.total), "')")), parse = TRUE)
```